# Issue with Multithreading

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

Hi I have a application that i made and I'm trying to speed it up by running multiple threads so far I have made it like this.

```
Public Class mainfrm
    Dim x As System.Threading.ThreadStart
    Public Function RunThreads(count As Integer, start As ThreadStart) As List(Of Thread)
        Dim list As New List(Of Thread)
        For i = 0 To count - 1
            Dim thread = New Thread(start)
            thread.Start()
            list.Add(thread)
        Next
        Return list
    End Function


Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RunThreads(10, x)
```

But when i click the button it gives me an error

[image]

Comment: what is value of x? the error message infer that x is null

Comment: I would suggest that you read the MSDN articles on multi-threading as your code makes little sense... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eed6swsx(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: What is *start* here?

Comment: Always use Option Strict On, it will prevent odd errors from happening. Also, if you are on .NET 4, you can switch to using Tasks instead of Threads, I find Tasks have a better programming model.

Comment: It's completely unclear why you want to implement threading. What's the use case? If its CPU bound then fine, I would suggest looking at the Task Parallel Library. If it IO bound then multithreading the code won't help you.

Comment: @PhilMurray: Good point. To OP: use the CPU profiler built in VS to determine if it's worth to go multi-threaded. Maybe it's not, and you've just spend several days working on it.

Comment: The thing is i want to speed up the whole program so it uses multiple processes :)

Comment: @JohnSmith: You never want to speed up a program, because you think it will be faster this way. You need to prove yourself that it really will be. Think of it this way - you need to pay a thousand dollars out of your pocket to some guy, who thinks your program needs to be improved. Would you trust this guy without any proof? Do not underestimate the power of a good argument, even if it's you against yourself.

Comment: @JohnSmith Using threading in a way that will not help will actually slow down your application. Creating a thread is an expensive task so try to understand your use case first. Don't preemptively optimise or micro optimise without understand a need to.

Comment: Its true guys but i want the application to process the stuff on button1 faster.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, x isn't instantiated.

The correct instruction to create your X is:

```
Private x As System.Threading.ThreadStart = New System.Threading.ThreadStart(SubToRun)
```

To call a sub that has to run in your threads, you can use this code.

```
Private x As New System.Threading.ThreadStart(SubToRun) 'Shortened version of above statement
Public Function RunThreads(count As Integer, start As ThreadStart) As List(Of Thread)
    Dim list As New List(Of Thread)()
    For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
        Dim thread As dynamic = New Thread(start)
        thread.Start()
        list.Add(thread)
    Next
    Return list
End Function


Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RunThreads(10, x)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub SubToRun()
    'DoTasks;
End Sub
```

Comment: After doing that i get now this
Dim x As System.Threading.ThreadStart = New System.Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf Button1_Click_1()

http://i.imgur.com/qFlkvhF.png

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't set X to run the method Button1_Click_1, since that'll end up in an infinite loop for sure. Looking at the error in your screenshot, it looks like it expects a parameterless method. So try that first.

Comment: You know im not a pro on this im pretty much beginner so may you explain more?.
Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer and extended it to a working code sample based on your OP code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll fare better with tasks and task factory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Dim task1 As Integer() = Task(Of Integer()).Factory.StartNew(
    Function()
        Dim IntArray(10) As Integer
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            IntArray(i) = i
        Next
        Return IntArray
    End Function
).Result

For Each i As Integer In task1
    Console.WriteLine(task1(i).ToString)
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```

Make sure there's a reason why your processing things on different threads though, the above example is just that, there would be no point using threading for something like this, but if you want to run a task and not lock up the UI then that would be a good use of threading.

Also worth noting that getting a result from a task will lock up the calling thread until it has completed.